# How to override Spring Security `HttpSecurity` `FilterOrderRegistration` so `OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter` is invoked before `AuthorizationFilter`?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application with the components in a single microservice for development and debugging.

1. OAuth2 Client (URI: /login/oauth2/code/internal-oauth2-login)
2. OAuth2 Server (URI: /oauth2/authorize, /oauth2/token)
3. Spring Security Authentication (URI: /login)

User authorization and authentication are OK, but `/userinfo` fails with HTTP 401. Both `InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService` and `InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService` seem to be populated correctly, so the issue seems to be `OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter` does not get invoked for the /userinfo endpoint. I suspect the reason is `AuthorizationFilter` is invoked before `OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter`, which throws an `Access Denied` exception and prevents invoking `OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter`.

Should these 4 OAuth2 `web` filters be ordered before `AuthorizationFilter`? I think so, but how do I override `HttpSecurity` and `FilterOrderRegistration` to order them before `AuthorizationFilter`?

1. org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter
2. org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter
3. org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter
4. org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter

For comparison, [`FilterOrderRegistration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6.0.2/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterOrderRegistration.java) lists 2 `client` OAuth2 filters, and they are before `AuthorizationFilter`.

1. org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
2. org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter

Here are some DEBUG/TRACE log snippets to show the URI call flow for successful authc and authn.

```
2023-03-20T13:16:51.619-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /oauth2/authorization/internal-oauth2-login HTTP/1.1
2023-03-20T13:16:51.686-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:8443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=internal-oauth2-login&scope=message.read%20message.write&state=z6vunrhrPacNLqAZlALL2KKs1ZgP7Fa22dI-IBDsIQc%3D&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/oauth2/code/internal-oauth2-login
2023-03-20T13:16:51.693-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-4] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=internal-oauth2-login&scope=message.read%20message.write&state=z6vunrhrPacNLqAZlALL2KKs1ZgP7Fa22dI-IBDsIQc%3D&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/oauth2/code/internal-oauth2-login HTTP/1.1
2023-03-20T13:16:51.746-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-4] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:8443/login
2023-03-20T13:16:51.752-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /login HTTP/1.1
2023-03-20T13:16:57.882-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [.1-8443-exec-10] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [POST /login HTTP/1.1
2023-03-20T13:16:57.961-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [.1-8443-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:8443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=internal-oauth2-login&scope=message.read%20message.write&state=z6vunrhrPacNLqAZlALL2KKs1ZgP7Fa22dI-IBDsIQc%3D&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/oauth2/code/internal-oauth2-login&continue
2023-03-20T13:16:57.966-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=internal-oauth2-login&scope=message.read%20message.write&state=z6vunrhrPacNLqAZlALL2KKs1ZgP7Fa22dI-IBDsIQc%3D&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/oauth2/code/internal-oauth2-login&continue HTTP/1.1
2023-03-20T13:17:06.241-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/oauth2/code/internal-oauth2-login?code=0INbSpRC_Cy5thVbknq8V-05i-6S_aCu3CvC4lDhQUlrmV61EqJtuelmL6QZgp8o_2TlApdgjBLp-jCYWytU1Iy1VTt0BA3bQzIcOztD8o4wLhcU3a02FTRZQdg2VN8y&state=z6vunrhrPacNLqAZlALL2KKs1ZgP7Fa22dI-IBDsIQc%3D
2023-03-20T13:17:06.248-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-9] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /login/oauth2/code/internal-oauth2-login?code=0INbSpRC_Cy5thVbknq8V-05i-6S_aCu3CvC4lDhQUlrmV61EqJtuelmL6QZgp8o_2TlApdgjBLp-jCYWytU1Iy1VTt0BA3bQzIcOztD8o4wLhcU3a02FTRZQdg2VN8y&state=z6vunrhrPacNLqAZlALL2KKs1ZgP7Fa22dI-IBDsIQc%3D HTTP/1.1
2023-03-20T13:17:06.368-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
2023-03-20T13:17:16.896-04:00  INFO 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] AllAuthenticationEventsListener          : AuthenticationSuccessEvent [source=OAuth2AccessTokenAuthenticationToken [Principal=OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken [Principal=internal-oauth2-login, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.915-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-9] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 << "{"access_token":"eyJraWQiOiIzZjNlZGVjNC04YTRkLTRiNWYtOWJhYy00ZjNlMWUzODBkNTYiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvcHN1c2VyIiwiYXVkIjoiaW50ZXJuYWwtb2F1dGgyLWxvZ2luIiwibmJmIjoxNjc5MzMyNjMwLCJzY29wZSI6WyJtZXNzYWdlLnJlYWQiLCJtZXNzYWdlLndyaXRlIl0sImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjg0NDMiLCJleHAiOjE2Nzk5Mzc0MzAsImlhdCI6MTY3OTMzMjYzMH0.NZuQsPjenBFrGR27Xjq2xGjFg708KaSspOscLOgO6QjgAmPjLJD2RXFsvsfTyNc3JkqCNIE70GhQK3OLHDPhVw_JJnxhg1epREbouFXSVnKqzJlJbNKKOyPFFUzKKQehlSSUbFq429SpTsVF1LtlmE8xOetIcr2l1X6PiHK0wKRaxTC5QPFVVMQFeaZJDqZ1mkY9XF45F-CDd3UCiSjuGTfxZ3PTxCJU6s7-qZtVsAtYidPzHP9DEtNVVOvh0rE7uq9dwzoZax_tXf_tOYFQAh-GhstNHM_pk0IUv5VgV39nVp2OBAt_k--M_Qyw-rhhcPlujiAgFsXbdcXIbWgQDA","refresh_token":"yVGK5diuvhF7EC4cQdgD_behdrw4p1ulmB5j8UYKdFMPPOrYNKbSof5R-efUzJyLiAIdKuf2I9SqJ5yq7_pX_4CEIwcyGjQosIBkry4DPIj5UR-Px0eM9t8VGVlATZ-o","scope":"message.read message.write","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":604799}[\r][\n]"
```

Notice the last line above shows OAuth2 Authz Server returning an `access_token` and `refresh_token`.

Right after this point, I see a /userinfo call arrived, and `AuthorizationFilter` rejects it.

```
2023-03-20T13:17:16.936-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /userinfo HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOiIzZjNlZGVjNC04YTRkLTRiNWYtOWJhYy00ZjNlMWUzODBkNTYiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvcHN1c2VyIiwiYXVkIjoiaW50ZXJuYWwtb2F1dGgyLWxvZ2luIiwibmJmIjoxNjc5MzMyNjMwLCJzY29wZSI6WyJtZXNzYWdlLnJlYWQiLCJtZXNzYWdlLndyaXRlIl0sImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjg0NDMiLCJleHAiOjE2Nzk5Mzc0MzAsImlhdCI6MTY3OTMzMjYzMH0.NZuQsPjenBFrGR27Xjq2xGjFg708KaSspOscLOgO6QjgAmPjLJD2RXFsvsfTyNc3JkqCNIE70GhQK3OLHDPhVw_JJnxhg1epREbouFXSVnKqzJlJbNKKOyPFFUzKKQehlSSUbFq429SpTsVF1LtlmE8xOetIcr2l1X6PiHK0wKRaxTC5QPFVVMQFeaZJDqZ1mkY9XF45F-CDd3UCiSjuGTfxZ3PTxCJU6s7-qZtVsAtYidPzHP9DEtNVVOvh0rE7uq9dwzoZax_tXf_tOYFQAh-GhstNHM_pk0IUv5VgV39nVp2OBAt_k--M_Qyw-rhhcPlujiAgFsXbdcXIbWgQDA
Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 0
Host: 127.0.0.1:8443
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.1.4 (Java/17.0.2)

]
```

Only 22 out of 26 filters are invoked.

```
2023-03-20T13:17:16.936-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve   : Incoming request /userinfo with originalRemoteAddr [127.0.0.1], originalRemoteHost=[127.0.0.1], originalSecure=[true], originalScheme=[https], originalServerName=[127.0.0.1], originalServerPort=[8443] will be seen as newRemoteAddr=[127.0.0.1], newRemoteHost=[127.0.0.1], newSecure=[true], newScheme=[https], newServerName=[127.0.0.1], newServerPort=[8443]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.936-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /userinfo
2023-03-20T13:17:16.937-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[null]' against GET /userinfo --> true
2023-03-20T13:17:16.937-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[null]' against GET /userinfo --> true
2023-03-20T13:17:16.937-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Calling hasUserDataPermission()
2023-03-20T13:17:16.937-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   User data constraint already satisfied
2023-03-20T13:17:16.937-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Calling accessControl()
2023-03-20T13:17:16.937-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   Checking roles null
2023-03-20T13:17:16.937-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      : Passing all access
2023-03-20T13:17:16.938-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Successfully passed all security constraints
2023-03-20T13:17:16.938-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning instance
2023-03-20T13:17:16.938-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4e57eb93
2023-03-20T13:17:16.938-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@bf0025d, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1b2213b2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4ff3ca23, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter@5b5f48d5, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@446dc997, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4bd7e0b6, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@17c7cc93, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@70c3c5d7, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@12b962b1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@3b5f72fa, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@472d7f34, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@5f6dd89c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@4ff233f9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@40af3dd8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@6eacf3be, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@7cc966a9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@ae4a043, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@29422e61, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@21312b5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@227ae4e4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@25bfc558, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@37a74cf4, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@77c4aeb6, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@121fe002, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@54aacbc7, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter@76fa3dd8]] (1/1)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.938-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /userinfo
2023-03-20T13:17:16.938-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.938-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationServerContextFilter (4/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (5/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (8/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (9/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter (10/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.939-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter (11/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter (12/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter (13/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login/oauth2/code/*']
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (14/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (15/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (16/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] .w.a.u.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter : Did not render default logout page since request did not match [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (17/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Did not process authentication request since failed to find username and password in Basic Authorization header
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (18/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 DEBUG 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (19/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.940-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (20/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.941-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (21/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.941-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (22/26)
2023-03-20T13:17:16.941-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@65ee8ea4]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.941-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]] and 4 interceptors
2023-03-20T13:17:16.944-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@65ee8ea4] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@4f072b08
2023-03-20T13:17:16.944-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2023-03-20T13:17:16.944-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.944-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.944-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.945-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] AllApplicationEventsListener             : AuthorizationDeniedEvent [source=SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@65ee8ea4]]
2023-03-20T13:17:16.945-04:00 TRACE 11004 --- [0.1-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
```

I placed a breakpoint in HttpSecurity to see the filter order computed in memory.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6.0.2/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L3019

Below is the in-memory sort order. Notice `AuthorizationFilter` is near the end, in position 22 out of 26. The 4 Oauth2 `web` filters are after `AuthorizationFilter`, which is why I suspect /userinfo endpoint is failing.

```
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@bf0025d, order=100}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1b2213b2, order=500}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4ff3ca23, order=600}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter@5b5f48d5, order=601}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@446dc997, order=800}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4bd7e0b6, order=1100}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@17c7cc93, order=1200}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@70c3c5d7, order=1499}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@12b962b1, order=1499}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@3b5f72fa, order=1499}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@472d7f34, order=1499}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@5f6dd89c, order=1501}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@4ff233f9, order=1700}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@40af3dd8, order=1900}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@6eacf3be, order=2100}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@7cc966a9, order=2200}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@ae4a043, order=2600}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@29422e61, order=2700}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@21312b5, order=2800}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@227ae4e4, order=3100}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@25bfc558, order=3400}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@37a74cf4, order=3600}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@77c4aeb6, order=3601}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@121fe002, order=3601}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@54aacbc7, order=3601}
OrderedFilter{filter=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter@76fa3dd8, order=3601}
```

AuthorizationFilter order 3600 seems to come from FilterOrderRegistration

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6.0.2/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterOrderRegistration.java#L118

I don't see a way to call HttpSecurity to force the 4 OAuth2 `web` filters to be after `AuthorizationFilter`. There are methods like `addFilterAfter`, `addFilterBefore`, and `addFilterAtOffsetOf`, but they seem to be for adding custom filters. I don't see a way to override the order of the built-in OAuth2 `web` filters.

I tried enabling DEBUG/TRACE logging, debugging Spring Security, reading the docs and APIs, searching Spring Security GitHub issues, and Googling the problem. I didn't find anything specific to this /userinfo authentication failure, other than comments that OAuth2 code grant flow without scope `openid` does a required call to /userinfo.

Comment: Spring Authorization Server's endpoint filters are designed to go after AuthorizationFilter since they require authorization. By default `/userinfo` requires that the client be authenticated in order to return a result. If that sounds wrong, I think what needs to be posted in your question is what creds you are passing to `/userinfo` since that should be the real source of the 401.

Comment: The Access Token JWT submitted to /userinfo can be decoded. The clientid is in the `aud` claim. I think the client would have had to be authenticated for OAuth2 Authz Server /oauth2/token endpoint to return this access_token for this user?
```
{
 "sub": "opsuser",
 "aud": "internal-oauth2-login",
 "nbf": 1679332630,
 "scope": [
  "message.read",
  "message.write"
 ],
 "iss": "https://127.0.0.1:8443",
 "exp": 1679937430,
 "iat": 1679332630
}
```

Comment: Logs show `access_token` returned by `/oauth2/token` at end of code grant flow.

Received [POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
http-outgoing-0 << "{"access_token":"eyJraWQiOiIzZjNlZGVjNC04YTRkLTRiNWYtOWJhYy00ZjNlMWUzODBkNTYiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvcHN1c2VyIiwiYXVkIjoiaW50ZXJuYWwtb2F1dGgyLWxvZ2luIiwibmJmIjoxNjc5MzMyNjMwLCJzY29wZSI6WyJtZXNzYWdlLnJlYWQiLCJtZXNzYWdlLndyaXRlIl0sImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjg0NDMiLCJleHAiOjE2Nzk5Mzc0MzAsImlhdCI6MTY3OTMzMjYzMH0.TRUNCATED"

OAuth2 client submits that `access_token` automatically to `/userinfo`, which gets rejected with 401.

Comment: Links to my OAuth2 Client and Server config files, in case it helps.

OAuth2 Client's ClientRegistration properties
- https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties#L170-L186

OAuth2 Server's RegisteredClientRepository
- https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/main/src/main/java/com/github/justincranford/spring/config/SecurityFilterChainConfig.java#L241-L267

Comment: Please add your configuration. You should have an `addFilter` in your security configuration or `addFilterBefore`/`addFilterAfter` which takes a position. Generally you want to position them before/after the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: Config links:
1. pom.xml: https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/3b90630d9b/pom.xml#L33
2. SecurityFilterChain: https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/3b90630d9b/src/main/java/com/github/justincranford/spring/config/SecurityFilterChainConfig.java#L121
3. ClientRegistration:  https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/3b90630d9b/src/main/resources/application.properties#L170
4. RegisteredClientRepository: https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/3b90630d9b/src/main/java/com/github/justincranford/spring/config/SecurityFilterChainConfig.java#L209